# Is $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{u}(d) \otimes \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{u}(d)=\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{u}(d^2)$?

Tags: lie-groups

Given a basis $a_i$ for the lie algebra $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{u}(d)$, does the set of elements $a_i \otimes a_j$ form a basis for $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{u}(d^2)$?

Comment: What are the dimensions of these two algebras ?

Comment: Ah, I see now that I should say that I wish to include the identity matrix in my basis set so that the set of elements in $a_i$ is $d^2$ not $d^2-1$. How should I modify the phrasing of my question?

Comment: Also, I noticed another mistake

Comment: (small note: you can save some typesetting pain by writing \mathfrak{su} vs. \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{u})

Comment: $\mathfrak{u}(d)$ get the dimension right. But then, the notion of a tensor product of Lie algebras, not sure it exists. It works though for usual algebras. So, $M_m\otimes M_n \simeq M_{mn}$ for algebras of matrices over a field.